# c++, evaluating expressions with multiple `&&`s and no operator of lower precedence

Tags: c++, expression, evaluation, operator-precedence, expression-evaluation

If an expression evaluates multiple `&&` operators, and does not evaluate any operators of lower precedence (eg. `||`, `?:`), will the expression evaluate to 0 as soon as one of the `&&`s return 0, or will it finish evaluating the remaining `&&`s?

For example,

```
q=0; w=1; e=1; r=1;
if(q && w && r && e) {}
```

Will this `if()` evaluate to false as soon as `q && w` evaluates to 0 (since the remaining `&&` must all evaluate to 0 regardless of the right hand operators)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, evaluation will terminate early ("short circuit") as soon as a false expression is encountered. There is one exception to this: if the `&&` operator has been overloaded for the relevant types of arguments. This is strongly discouraged and extremely rare, but could happen.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does do short-circuit evaluation, for built-in types.  Custom types where you've overloaded `&&` or `||` won't have short-circuiting performed, which can cause subtle bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already stated the answer (i.e. "yes").

I will answer to add an example of one particularly idiomatic usage of this:

```
if ((p != NULL) && (*p == 42))
{
    /* Do something */
}
```

This would have to be written in a much clumsier manner if short-circuiting didn't happen.

Note that you can also use this in a Perl-esque manner, e.g.:

```
someCondition && doSomething();
```

so `doSomething()` only gets called if `someCondition` is `true`.  But this only compiles if `doSomething()` returns a type that can be converted to `bool`, and it's not considered idiomatic C++.  (Note also that this technique doesn't compile in C.)