# Why the output won't be this in the code?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int i = -3, j = 2, k = 0, m;
m = ++i && ++j || ++k;
printf("%d %d %d %d\n",i,j,k,m);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to learn about associativity and precedence of operators in C. Here, The output comes out to be `-2 3 0 1`, but I think the output should be `-2 3 1 1` because `k` is also pre-incremented. Why that won't be the answer? Thanks!

Comment: why would you waste time to execute the commands after || when the statement before is already true?

Comment: Whoa! After much searching, didnt find it, otherwise wouldn't have posted the question in the first place. Anyways, no need to downvote, and yeah, nice answer. :)

Comment: Is the code not explained in the textbook and/or web page?  Why would you want us to explain it, (again, again)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `||` has short-circuit evaluation, which means that the right hand side gets evaluated only if the left hand side is `false`. In your case this doesn't happen since both `i` and `j` have values different than `0`after being incremented, so the `++k` doesn't get executed

The same behavior occurs when you have a `&&` in which the LHS expressions evaluates to `false`

Comment: Does this happen with only `||` operator, or is true for any other operator too? Like `&&` , if LHS comes out to be `0` or `false`, then RHS is not evaluated?

Comment: This is true also for the &&, thanks for pointing out, I'll edit my answer!

Comment: and, if it happens with any other operator too, please add that too. Thanks! :)

Comment: @JohnLui: It's true for every *logic* operator. It does not apply to arithmetic and bitwise boolean operators.

Answer (score 4):

The expression before the `||` is true so the part after the `||` that is the ++K does not get executed so `k` wont be incremented. Hence the value of K remains 0 and the value of m is one since the left of `||` is true and `true || <anything>` is always `true`.

Answer (score 2):

`1 || 0 = 1` and `1 || 1 = 0`

So once the first condition is TRUE while evaluating statement with `||` operator there is no need to evaluate the second expression that is what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confused with [*Precedence* and *Order of evaluation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx).

The order of evaluation of logical *OR* `||` is left to right.

So if `left = true` then `left || right` will never execute `right`. In your code exactly same happened.

As you know, any non zero value treated as `true` in C, hence, `++i` or `-2` is `true`. So,

```
 m = ++i && ++j || ++k;
 m = (true && true) || bla bla bla; //right not even checked!
 m = true 
 m = 1
```

And you get the output as expected.

For experiment, instead of `i = -3` try `i = -1`, then the scenario will be

```
 m = ++i && ++j || ++k;
 m = false && (not going to evaluate) || ++k;
 m = false || true;
 m = true 
 m = 1
```

And output will be: `0 2 1 1`

Comment: Wait, I got your point, but, since `&&` has a higher precedence than `||` wont that get executed first and then its result will be used for evaluating `||`?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, got it. The answer has clear explanation of my doubt. Thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: @JohnLui Precedence only guarantees that the expression in itself will be  evaluated as `((++i) && (++j)) || ...`. But it has nothing to do with the order in which the operands of each operator gets evaluated! Take plain maths, `1 + 2 + 3 * 4` is guaranteed to be equal to `1 + 2 + (3 * 4)`, but the precedence rules doesn't tell you that you must start calculating `1+2` before you calculate `3*4`. You might as well do it the other way around. Math doesn't care, because you'll get the same result. In C programming however, two different orders of evaluation may cause different results.