# Explanation for this function's output

Tags: c, output, logical-operators, integer-arithmetic

I am doing review questions which ask me "What is the output of the following," and I am having some trouble understanding something about this function:

```
int a = 1, b = 1, c = -1;
c = --a && b++;
printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
```

The output is 010. My question is about line 2, `c = --a && b++`. How is this line processed, and how does it work/change the values? And if it were `c = --a || b++`? From my understanding I thought the output would be 020.

Comment: Learn about pre and post in/decreament operator properties.

Comment: Before you add an answer, note that `--a && b++` short circuits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is short-circuiting logical operators mandated? And evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order)

Answer (score 12):

The key concept to understanding the result is [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of Boolean operators (`&&` and `||`) -- if, after evaluating the left-hand side of a Boolean operator, the value of the right-hand side *cannot affect the overall result*, then it will not be evaluated *and any side-effects it would produce will not happen*.

In the first case, since `--a` evaluates to `0` (=false) the second part of `... && ...` is not evaluated, since "*false AND anything*" will always be false.  Specifically, `b++` is never executed, and so its value remains `1` in the output.

In the case of `--a || b++`, the value of the whole expression *cannot* be determined by the left-hand side ("*false OR something*" can still be true) so the `b++` *is* evaluated (and it's side-effect, incrementing `b`, happens).

The other concept needed to fully understand the results is the difference between pre- and post-increment/decrement operators.  If the `--` or `++` appears *before* the variable (as in `--a`) then the variable is decremented or incremented first and *new* value is used to evaluate the whole expression.  If the `--` or `++` appears *after* the variable (as in `b++`) then the *current* value of the variable is used to evaluate the expression and the increment/decrement happens after this has happened.

It should be noted that expressions that try to combine two or more instances of `--`/`++` *of the same variable* (e.g. `a++ + ++a`) are quite likely to invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) -- the result may vary by platform, compiler, compiler and even the time of day.

Comment: a complete answer should preferentially touch on the difference between pre- and post-increment

Answer (score 6):

In the expression `c = --a && b++`, `a` gets decreased and returned. Now the second argument of the expression `--a && b++` is not evaluated because of [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)---once we see that `--a==0` we already know that the expression will be `0` *regardless* of what is the other argument---, so `b` remains unchanged.

Decreased `a` is `0` and `b` remains `1`.

The output is, as you suggest, `0 1 0`.

Regarding the second question, if you write `c = --a || b++`, the variable `a` again goes to zero but the expression can still evaluate to true---we must thus evaluate the second part as well, thus executing `b++` which returns `1` and increases `b`. In this case the output would be `0 2 1`, because `c` is assigned the value of `0 || 1` which is `1`.

In short, read up on

- [pre- and post-increment in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept) and on
- [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Yeah, because of [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation); I updated the answer

Comment: The missing piece is `--a && b++` short circuits. `--a` is false so `b++` is never executed.

Answer (score 3):

The thing you need to focus on here first is the properties of prefix and postfix operators and their differences.

- For Postfix increment and decrement operators, `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.4, (*emphasis mine*)

  > **The result of the postfix `++` operator is the value of the operand**. As a side effect, the
  >   value of the operand object is incremented [...] The postfix `--` operator is analogous to the postfix `++` operator, except that the value of
  >   the operand is decremented.
- For Prefix increment and decrement operators, `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.1, (*emphasis mine*)

  > **The value of the operand of the prefix `++` operator is incremented.** The result is the new
  >   value of the operand after incrementation. [...] The prefix `--` operator is analogous to the prefix `++` operator, except that the value of the
  >   operand is decremented.

Now, there comes the property of the Logical AND (`&&`) operator. From chapter §6.5.13, (*again, emphasis mine*)

> the `&&` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
>   if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of
>   the first and second operands. **If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.** [...]

So, in your case,

```
int a = 1, b = 1, c = -1;
c = --a && b++;
```

gets evaluated as

```
c = 0 && .....; // done..., a is decremented to 0, 
                //            so, LHS of && is 0, RHS is not evaluated,
                //            b remains 1
                //            and finally, C gets 0.
```

On the other hand, if logical OR (`||`) would have been used, then, as per the property, mentioned in chapter §6.5.14

> [...] the `||` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the
>   second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first
>   and second operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is
>   not evaluated.**

So, for the case

```
int a = 1, b = 1, c = -1;
c = --a || b++;
```

it will be evaluated as

```
c = 0 || 1;   //yes, b's value will be used, and then incremented.
```

So,

```
printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
```

will be

```
0 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The line :

```
c = --a && b++;
```

decreases `a` to `0`, so the statement `0 && anything else` results to `0`. This is why `a` and `c` result to `0`, as it seems you have understood.

Now let's see the part you don't get. When `a` is evaluated to `0`, the right part of `&&` does not need to be evaluated, as no matter what the value of the right part will be calculated to be, the result will be `0`. This means that `b++` will not be evaluated and therefore `b` will retain its initial value. This is why you see the value `1` instead of `2`, and consequently the output `0 1 0` instead of `0 2 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = --a && b++;
```

In this first `--a` is evaulated and `a` becomes `0` , as soon as 1 operand of `&&` is false , `b++` is not evaluated , therefore ,`b` remains `1` and `c` becomes `0`.

Answer (score 1):

b++ is simply never executed because --a evaluates to false in an and condition.
The right side of the and is never executed because not needed. Hence b is never incremented and hence the output you did not expect.

Answer (score -2):

--a : mean you decrease a before do the line. b++: increase b after do the line. so that c ( at that time )  = 0+1 =1; then: a =0, b = 2, c =1; OK

Comment: oh, I misunderstand && with +.